# Button не отжимается после выполнения Command

Tags: c#, wpf

Иногда кнопка после выполнения команды не становится активной.
Помогает клик по форме. Скажете пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

[image: Анимация поведения кнопки]

**XAML:**

```
    <Button
        Grid.Column="1"
        Height="20"
        Margin="10,5"
        Command="{Binding DoneCommand}"
        Content="Done" />
```

**C#:**

```
private readonly RaiseCommand doneCommand;
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;

private object _currentUserState;
private int _currentProgress;

public RaiseCommand DoneCommand
{
    get { return doneCommand; }
}

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    doneCommand = new RaiseCommand(o => worker.RunWorkerAsync(), o => !worker.IsBusy);

    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += DoDoneCommand;
    worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void DoDoneCommand(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentUserState = e.UserState;
    CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Класс `RaiseCommand`:**

```
public class RaiseCommand : ICommand
    {
        readonly Action<object> _action;
        readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public RaiseCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

        public RaiseCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            _action = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без клика по окну не обновляется состояние кнопки и не вызывается `CanExecute`, соответственно, кнопка остается неактивной.

**Обновленный ответ:** Для явного обновления интерфейса вручную можете попробовать вызвать [`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) по завершении потока:

```
private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Из документации:

> The CommandManager only pays attention to certain conditions in determining when the command target has changed, such as change in keyboard focus. In situations where the CommandManager does not sufficiently determine a change in conditions that cause a command to not be able to execute, InvalidateRequerySuggested can be called to force the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event.

**Ответ до обновления:** Можно попробовать явно вызвать `CanExecuteChanged` после завершения `BackgroundWorker`. Для этого в комманду добавляем свое событие и метод его вызова:

```
//объявляем событие
private event EventHandler InternalCanExecuteChanged;

//привязываем его к CanExecuteChanged 
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add
    {
        InternalCanExecuteChanged += value;
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        InternalCanExecuteChanged -= value;
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}

//метод для вызова
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    var handler = InternalCanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

и обращаемся к методу после завершения потока:

```
private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    doneCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Comment: Тогда возникает вопрос почему "Иногда..."? Один раз нормально... другой с "глюком". От чего зависит этот хаотичный порядок?

Comment: @KirillK. Почему-то у меня на Вашем примере кнопка стабильно неактивна после нажатия на OK в MessageBox (Enter вызывает событие у окна, т.ч. после нажатия на Enter кнопка становится активной). Поэтому не могу сказать из-за чего возникает нестабильность, к сожалению.

Comment: @KirillK. возможно, окно привязано к другим свойствам (`CurrentProgress`, `CurrentUserState`) и в части случаев происходит обновление интерфейса не через команду. Попробуйте отключить всю привязку к ViewModel и оставить только команду. Будет ли кнопка стабильно неактивна в данном случае?

Comment: Попробовал выключить все кроме объявления переменных, "хаотичный баг" остался. У Вас VS 2017?

Comment: @KirillK. Ну тогда точно не знаю. Попробуйте воспроизвести на чистом проекте с одной кнопкой. У меня 2015, но навряд ли это связано с IDE.

Comment: Я в прошлый раз оказывается не убрал worker. Сейчас убрал теперь кнопка работает нормально, только одно НО она не disable'тся даже когда появляется MessageBox.

Comment: @KirillK. Возможно, без фонового потока, фокус будет возвращаться к форме сам по себе. Как-то даже не подумал об этом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68740/discussion-between-kirill-k-and-default-locale).

Comment: А по чату уведомления приходят?

Answer (score 2):

Позволю себе написать ответ, хотя он только косвенно относится к озвученному вопросу.

Если вы хотите блокировать активность кнопки до тех пор пока некоторая длительная операция будет завершена, то возможно правильным решением будет воспользоваться асинхронными командами вместо того, чтобы применять немного устаревший [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

По идее асинхронные версии команд должны предоставляться основными библиотеками упрощающими разработку WPF проекты.

Если по каким-то причинам вы не хотите их подключать, то можно найти реализации AsyncCommand в интернете.

Например, отличная статья

[Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx)

---

Чтобы ответ был более полным приведу пример тривиального таймера обратного отсчета, когда мы не можем (не должны) запускать новый до истечения предыдущего.

Разметка

```
<Button
    Grid.Row="0"
    Margin="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Command="{Binding Start}"
    Content="Запустить"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Idle}" />
<TextBlock
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="40"
    Text="{Binding Count}" />
```

и контекст

```
let source = Bind.createSource()

let step = 1000
let startInt = 10

let Count = Mutable.create startInt

let start _ =
    async {
        while Count.Value > 0 do
            do! Async.Sleep step
            Mutable.step (fun x -> x - 1) Count
        return startInt
    }

Bind.Explicit.oneWay source "Count" Count
Bind.Explicit.createCommand "Start" source
|> Observable.mapAsyncTracked start source.IdleTracker
|> Observable.subscribe (Mutable.set Count)
|> source.AddDisposable
```

При написании использована библиотека [Gjallarhorn.Bindable.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gjallarhorn.Bindable.Wpf/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]